# Coloring cells correctly when using tabu, multicolumn, and multirow

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, tabu, rowcolor

I have made the following table header using tabu, however as you can see there is a white line separating the two merged cells of the `\multirow`. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

[image]

**Code used to produce the above table:**

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \captionabove{Overall bond energies for different base pairs}
  \begin{tabu} to 0.95\textwidth { | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | }
    \hline
    \taburowcolors 1{lightgray .. lightgray}
                                & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$R_e$ [\AA]} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\Delta E$ [eV]} \\ \tabucline{2-} \rowcolor{lightgray}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Structure} & this work & reference & difference & this work & reference & difference \\ \hline
  \end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551564/white-row-in-merged-cells/551567#551567  -- duplicate

Comment: be aware that tabu is broken, see the readme and the issues here https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu/