# Remove non-colour space between multirow cells in table

Tags: tables, multirow, colortbl

I'm creating a longtable with a number of coloured cells and some cells split into multirows, using rmarkdown:

```
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{multirow}
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

\begin{landscape}

\centering
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{longtable} {p{0.08\linewidth}  >{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}  p{0.05\linewidth} p{0.04\linewidth}  p{0.05\linewidth} >{\raggedright}p{0.08\linewidth}  >{\raggedright}p{0.1\linewidth}p{00.06\linewidth}  p{0.06\linewidth}p{0.06\linewidth}p{0.06\linewidth} p{0.12\linewidth}p{0.12\linewidth}}
First author, Year          & Population                                    & Mean age            & Participants (n)       & Follow up (years)    & Analysis                                      & Outcome                                  & 1st                                                                    & 2nd                                                                       & 3rd                                                                & 4th                                                                                    & Other significant                                                                          & Non-significant                                                      \\
\multirow{3}{*}{Ryu 2009}  & \multirow{3}{*}{Men, age
  30-59}             & \multirow{3}{*}{37} & \multirow{3}{*}{10685} & \multirow{3}{*}{3.8} & \multirow{3}{*}{}                            & \multirow{3}{0.1\linewidth}{Incident
  CKD (eGFR60)} & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}                                       & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}                                          & \multirow{3}{*}{~}                                                 & \multirow{3}{*}{~}                                                                     & \multirow{3}{*}{HOMA-IR}                                                                   & {\cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,0.4}}\textit{Obesity}                           \\
                            &                                               &                     &                        &                      &                                               &                                          & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}                                       & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}                                          &                                                                    &                                                                                        &                                                                                            & {\cellcolor[rgb]{1,0.498,0.38}}\textit{Hypertension}                 \\
                            &                                               &                     &                        &                      &                                               &                                          & \multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}Low HDL}              & \multirow{-3}{*}{{\cellcolor[rgb]{0.706,0.561,1}}Triglycerides}           &                                                                    &                                                                                        &                                                                                            & {\cellcolor[rgb]{0.675,0.957,0.635}}\textit{Fasting glucose}         \\
                        
                                    
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

[image]

How do I remove the spaces between the multirow cells (in this case the cells which contain "Low HDL" and "Tricglycerides") so that they colour appears unbroken?

Comment: Actually, the lines don't appear when I view the output in a proper pdf viewer such as adobe

Comment: You might have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596036/113546).